# How to replace fields in data frame containing sub-strings given in list-dictionary and avoid ValueError?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame like this (Author, Title, and Year are not relevant, therefore A, T, and Y):

```
Author  Title  Year  Country    
A       T      Y     UK. cat@mail.uk
A       T      Y     U.S.A.
A       T      Y     University of Cambridge
A       T      Y     United Kingdom
A       T      Y     somename@uconn.edu
```

What I want to achieve, is a data frame with a "clean" Country column:

```
Author  Title  Year  Country    
A       T      Y     UK
A       T      Y     USA
A       T      Y     UK
A       T      Y     UK
A       T      Y     USA
```

To do that I have created a (list) dictionary:

```
UK = ['UK.', 'Cambridge', 'United Kingdom']
USA = ['U.S.A.', 'conn.edu']
my_dict = {'UK': UK, 'USA': USA}
```

To feed into the following function to clean up:

```
def clean_country(country_dict):
    for key in country_dict:
        for value in country_dict[key]:
            if df['Country'].str.contains(value):
                df['Country'] = np.where(value, key, df['Country'].str.replace('-', ' '))
            return df
        else:
            continue

clean_country(my_dict)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in clean_country
  File "/Users/birgitte/PycharmProjects/text/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

When using the following inside the function:

`df['Country'].str.contains(value).all()`: False (not all fields contain the value). None of the Country-fields is being changed.

`df['Country'].str.contains(value).any()`: True (some fields contain the value). Results in `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'UK'`

`df['Country'].str.contains(value).item()`: Results in `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`

`df['Country'].str.contains(value).bool()`: Result in `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Any help on how I can achieve a "clean" Country column is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function in DataFrame

```
# Replacement logic

def replace(x):
    for key in country_dict:
        for value in country_dict[key]:
            if value in x:
                return key
    return x

# use either ways:

df['Country'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda x: replace(x))

# or

df['Country'] = df['Country'].apply(replace)
```

**Updated:**

Use replace method correctly and fix a copy paste error in checking if a value exists in a string.

Comment: I tried:
`def replace(x):
    for key in my_dict:
        for value in my_dict[key]:
            if x.contains(value):
                return key
    return x`

`df['Country'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda x: replace)`

But that resulted in a Country column where all fields are replaced with: <function replace at 0x119e7de60>

Comment: Thanks :) 
Unfortunately, when I use:
`def replace(x):
    for key in my_dict:
        for value in my_dict[key]:
            if x.contains(value):
                return key
    return x` 
I get: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains' ` (sorry, posted the wrong try-out I did after the real one)

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. there was a copy-paste error on my end:

`x.contains(value)` should be `value in x`